# How to copy code between different organization github

Tags: git, github, github-actions

I want to copy a github code repository from organization A to organization B. If any PR is merged in master branch of organization A then same PR/changes must reflect in organization B master branch.

For this to work I used github action. Following is the workflow for the action:

```
name: CI

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "main" ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "main" ]

  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Run a one-line script
        run: |
          git remote add orgb https://${{ secrets.GIT_ACCESS_TOKEN }}@github.com/orgb/backend.git
          git remote -v
          git fetch orgb
          git push -f orgb $GITHUB_SHA:main
```

But I am getting following error

```
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/orgb/backend.git/' not found
Error: Process completed with exit code 128.
```

The same steps works locally.

When added a step

```
- name: Checkout backend from orgb
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          repository: orgb/backend
          path: backend
          token: <token>
```

Then the job step is executing it

How to solve this?

Also When used https://github.com/marketplace/actions/mirroring-repository
Got this error:

```
Load key "/github/home/.ssh/id_rsa": invalid format
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

Which git hooks will be helpful? What other approach should be followed?

Comment: Locally I checked it is working. I haven't check this existing action. I will try the one

Answer (score 1):

[`mirroring-repository`](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/mirroring-repository) should be enough.

The `invalid format`, seen also in [repository-mirroring-action issue 14](https://github.com/pixta-dev/repository-mirroring-action/issues/14) can be the result of a private key with a passphrase.

Try and generate a dedicate key *without* passphrase (and add the public key to your profile)

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -P "" -f ~/.ssh/mirrorKey
                  ^^^^^
                    |
                     -- no passphrase
```

Comment: I did generated the key without passphrase. And added the public key to profile. Also added same public key in github secrets for getting read by the job

Comment: @puneetShah But that action mentions "Add the *private* key as a secret to your workflow"

Comment: Correct. It is working after adding private key. Thanks for pointing it out. I believe mirroring-repository doesn't support specific branch commit

Comment: @puneetShah Correct. This is followed by https://github.com/pixta-dev/repository-mirroring-action/issues/2